# Parsing local XML files in a directory using R

Tags: r, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to write a function parsing several .xml files in one directory and returning .txt files.

When I run this code on one file, everything is fine:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("/directory/file.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
rootnode <- xmlRoot(doc)
text <- xpathSApply(rootnode, "//TEI.2/text/body/sentence/word", xmlGetAttr, 'form')
write.table(text, file = "file.txt", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

However, when I try to read several files at once I get the error "XML content does not seem to be XML". Here is the code I tried:

```
parse.xml.directory <- function(directory) {
        filenames <- list.files(directory)
        for (i in filenames){
                url = paste("/", "directory", "/", "i", sep = "")
                doc <- xmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
                rootnode  <- xmlRoot(doc)
                text <- xpathSApply(rootnode, "//TEI.2/text/body/sentence/word", xmlGetAttr, 'form')
                outname <-  paste(filenames[i], ".txt", sep= "")
                write.table(text, outname, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
                }
}
```

I understand that the problem emerges when xmlTreeParse is running, but I do not understand how to fix it. I am new to R and would appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Most likely `list.files(directory)` is returning some non XML files.  Try using the 'pattern=".xml"' option to filter the file list.  Another option is to add a `print()` statement to your loop to identify the file causing the problem.

Comment: @Dave2e, thank you! Added 'pattern=".xml"', but the problem remains. Do you mean adding just print() or something else should be specified in the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I fixed it! The simple answer is that I should have removed quotation marks from the paste function. Here is how it should look like:

```
parse.xml.directory <- function(directory) {
    filenames <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".xml")
    for (i in filenames){
            url = paste(directory, "/", i, sep = "") ##here are the changes
            doc <- xmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = TRUE, isURL = F)
            rootnode  <- xmlRoot(doc)
            text <- xpathSApply(rootnode, "//TEI.2/text/body/sentence/word", xmlGetAttr, 'form')
            y <-gsub(".xml","", i) ##here too
            outname <-  paste(y, ".txt", sep= "") 
            write.table(text, outname, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
            }
```

}

It now works!